# Inertiajs put redirect issue

Tags: inertiajs

I have a button on vue calling a function to redirect back to Laravel route.

I would like to ask the user if he really want to perform the operation.
If he reply "Cancel" I need to avoid redirecting and do nothing

First I tried this way, but it does not ask for confirmation:

```
Inertia.put(route('disable-utente', row.id), 
  { onBefore: () => { 
    confirm('Do you really want to continue ?')
  }}
)
```

Then I tried this way; it shows the dialog but put to the route even if I clicked cancel on the confirmation dialog

```
Inertia.visit(route('disable-utente', row.id),
  {
    method: 'put',
    onBefore: () => { confirm('Do you really want to continue?') }
  } 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the return

```
Inertia.put(route('disable-utente', row.id), 
{ onBefore: () => { 
    return confirm('Do you really want to continue ?')
}}
)
```

Comment: thank you @Garry I used your suggestion on the other way, that Inertia.visit;

in your solution, I would have to add also a second parameter like row.id as "data" as per documentation

Answer (score 0):

based on @Garry suggestion here is what finally worked for me

```
Inertia.visit(route('disable-utente', row.id),
      {
        method: 'put',
        onBefore: () => { return confirm('Do you really want to continue?')}
      }
    )
```

or

```
Inertia.put(route('disable-utente', row.id), row.id,
      { onBefore: () => { 
          return confirm('Do you really want to continue?')
      }}
    )
```